# singlelineedit & datawindow/datastore - Sybase

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I want to use singlelineedit as input.
So I've 4 input fields and a button.
I want to pass the inputs to datawindow/datastore when i click the button. 
How do I write the code in the clicked event of the button?

I've created a datawindow namely dw_insert_into_table1 which built on top of a store procedure which is expecting 4 arguments.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks xlat & Terry! You're awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long rows
rows = dw_insert_into_table1.retrieve( sle_input_1.text, &
    sle_input_2.text, sle_input_3.text, sle_input_4.text )
```

Note that dw_insert_into_table1 must have been connected to a transaction object
with setTransobject or setTrans method before a call to the retrieve method, and be sure to pass input field value in the right order, the one you have defined your retrival arguments in the datawindow definition.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is the example if you're expecting four strings. (Depending on how much PB experience you've had, it may be) Obviously you'll need to convert (e.g. Long (sle_1.text)) if the DataWindow is expecting another data type. Or, you could use an EditMask control, which will change your solution somewhat, but will assure the user is entering a number when you want a number.